# I do have .NET 4.6.2 but VS still complains about it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

So I am trying to open one of my team's project and I think it is in .NET 4.6.2. and it gave me usual error of you do not have this framework version, do you want to install it?

So I went ahead and installed that version and also restarted my computer. After that even if I see in my Control panel that I have already installed .NET Framework 4.6.2 Visual studio continues to complain about not having that particular version of .NET

Any idea on how to address this issue?

Comment: You need the developer pack, not just the runtine

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321

Comment: Is this a UWP or WPF / Desktop application?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII: No it is a WebAPI application.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Your solution worked. Thank you so much for your input.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer and included the link vcjones added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the .NET 4.6.2 targeting pack, not just the runtime.

Download can download it here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321

Comment: @CoffeeBean The .NET 4.6.2 developer pack is the .NET 4.6.2 targeting pack + the .NET 4.6.2 SDK. The SDK is not needed to solve the OP's issue.